# Send JSON through ActiveMQ

Tags: c#, json.net, activemq-classic

I'm trying to send a JSON format through `ActiveMQ` (C# Console Application), but right now I'm stock in the following:

1. If I send the direct JSON serialization (as string) the system adds backward slashes "\" to the text, which makes my listener unable to process the information.
2. I can remove the backward slashes by doing a JToken Parse, but I cannot send the var on `ActiveMQ` (`ITextMessage` requests a String, I'm sending a JToken) and of course if I do cast of the JToken to string I found again the backward slashes "\"

Any clue on how I can achieve my goal???

```
String IP = "172.29.75.43:61616";
String QueuesNameESF = "queue://MES2WMSTVOFFLINE";
try
{
    Uri _uri = new Uri(String.Concat("activemq:tcp://" + IP));
    IConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory(_uri);
    using (IConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection())
    {
        using (ISession session = conn.CreateSession())
        {
            IDestination destination = SessionUtil.GetDestination(session, QueuesNameESF);
            using (IMessageProducer producer = session.CreateProducer(destination))
            {
                SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=false;Data Source=smxsql08svr01;initial catalog=BSS;user id=sa;password=newshamu;Max Pool Size=75000");
                SqlConnection internalConnection = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=false;Data Source=smxsql08svr01;initial catalog=BSS;user id=sa;password=newshamu;Max Pool Size=75000");
                String SearchPallet;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                dbConnection.Open();

                SearchPallet = "";
                SearchPallet = "Select Replace(Replace(Replace((Convert(varchar,GETDATE(),120) + Palletnum),'-',''),' ',''),':','')  as 'ID', ";
                SearchPallet += "'Y' as 'beFull','ZJ' as 'ext1','' as 'ext2','Y'as 'isCM',Part_Number as 'itemCode',linea as 'line',";
                SearchPallet += "Case When len(Part_Number) = 12 then RIGHT(Part_Number,7) else RIGHT(Part_Number,8) end as 'lot',";
                SearchPallet += "Palletnum as 'mainPallet',GETDATE() as 'sendTime','BSS' as'sender','8170' as'werks' From Finishgoods ";
                //Remove if not test
                SearchPallet += "Where PalletNum = @Palletnum GROUP by PalletNum,Part_Number,linea";
                cmd.CommandText = SearchPallet;
                cmd.Connection = dbConnection;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Palletnum", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "PT01929734";//Pallet;//"PT01929734";
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                FirstLevel product = new FirstLevel();
                if (rdr.Read())
                {
                    //FirstLevel product = new FirstLevel();
                    product.guid = rdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    product.beFull = rdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    SecondLevel msg = new SecondLevel();
                    msg.carton = rdr.GetValue(8).ToString();
                    List<ThirdLevel> serials = new List<ThirdLevel>();

                    ThirdLevel sn = new ThirdLevel();
                    String SearchSN = "Select barcodenum as 'serNo',''as 'ext1',''as 'ext2' From Finishgoods where palletnum = @palletnum";
                    SqlCommand cmd_sn = new SqlCommand();
                    internalConnection.Open();
                    cmd_sn.Connection = internalConnection;
                    cmd_sn.CommandText = SearchSN;
                    cmd_sn.Parameters.Add("@Palletnum", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "PT01929734";
                    SqlDataReader rdr_sn = cmd_sn.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdr_sn.Read())
                    {
                        sn.serNo = rdr_sn.GetValue(0).ToString();
                        sn.ext1 = rdr_sn.GetValue(1).ToString();
                        sn.ext2 = rdr_sn.GetValue(2).ToString();
                        serials.Add(sn);
                    }
                    rdr_sn.Close();
                    cmd_sn.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd_sn.Dispose();
                    internalConnection.Close();
                    msg.serNoMsg = serials;
                    product.crtonMsg = msg;
                    product.ext1 = rdr.GetValue(2).ToString();
                    product.ext2 = rdr.GetValue(3).ToString();
                    product.isCM = rdr.GetValue(4).ToString();
                    product.itemCode = rdr.GetValue(5).ToString();
                    product.line = rdr.GetValue(6).ToString();
                    product.lot = rdr.GetValue(7).ToString();
                    product.mainPallet = rdr.GetValue(8).ToString();
                    product.sendTime = rdr.GetValue(9).ToString();
                    product.sender = rdr.GetValue(10).ToString();
                    product.werks = rdr.GetValue(11).ToString();
                }
                rdr.Close();
                string json_ = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
                var json = JToken.Parse(json_);
                conn.Start();
                ITextMessage request = session.CreateTextMessage(json); //Here I need to send the JSON
                producer.Send(request);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("send succeed");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Receive Failed");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Why not to use a MapMessage for publishing ?

Comment: Hello, could you give me a sample? I'm new on MQ